# number of new/unread SharePoint newsfeeds on tile

Tags: development, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I built a dashboard and want to show up on a tile/button the number of new newsfeeds (following, everyone, mention).

I read the specs from Microsoft about the social feed API:
[Social feed REST API reference for SharePoint - My Unread Mention Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/dn155789.aspx#bk_myUnreadMentionCount)

But this one only shows the number of unread mentions, but not the number of new newsfeeds.
When I go to my MySite, it shows me the numbers as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

dashboard tile looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to get the number (e.g. 18) of unread "following" and "everyone" posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a Social feed REST API(only provide api to get unread Mention count) to get the unread "following" and "everyone" in currently. Check the official document below:

[Social feed REST API reference for SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/social-feed-rest-api-reference-for-sharepoint)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I knew that there is no API to get unread "following" and "everyone" as I mentioned in my question. Therefor I am interesting to other methods to get the unread "following" and "everyone"

Comment: I can't find SharePoint API provide a method to achieve it currently, as a workaround, you can check if can get the data from content database(Microsoft not recommend this way).